# PHP.ini: php_pdo_sqlite.dll or php_sqlite3.dll or both?

Tags: php, dll, sqlite

I am on PHP 5.5.27 and I want to use SQLite in a ZF2 application. I understand I have to enable `.ddl` libraries in my `php.ini` (I am on windows 10), but the documentation is unclear.

There are two `.dll` libraries mentioned in my `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
```

Which one should I enable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to interact with SQLite:

`php_sqlite3.dll` will give you access to the [SQLite3 database extension functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) - so you'll be able to use PHP's specific SQLite functions.

`php_pdo_sqlite.dll` will give you access to the [PDO's SQLite driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php) - so you'll be able to use PDO to access SQLite functions.

If you're not sure what your framework needs, you can activate both of them. If you want to just start with one of them, I'd go for the PDO driver, which will let change to a different DB in the future more easily, should you need to.